# How to handle OnBackKeyPress when keyboard is open

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to override back key button

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
```

But it can't be handled until screen keyboard is open. Is any way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to navigate away from the app/page when the Back key is pressed when the Keyboard is Up? The Question is not clear.

Comment: Yes, OnBackKeyPress won't be called with the on-screen keyboard open. I expect this is by design as the user expects the back button to dismiss the keyboard as an OS-level interaction. Why are you trying to override this behaviour? I should add that using the back button for anything other than going backwards/cancelling something is against the Windows Phone guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Try handling `KeyUp` event in your page and check the key code in its handler. This method was working on Silverlight with SIP opened, I'm pretty sure it will work on WinRT too.

```
void KeyUpHandler(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Back)
    {
        // The back button has been clicked
    }
}
```